# Creating dynamic keys values in json array in google apps script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I have this workbook of data - [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zxKhHaqa31wLE9ea98PMtleKXMcJF98sQDGLP1ehgU8/edit?usp=sharing)

Now, the actual dataset will probably have duplicates of the same company and **my end goal is to create a timeline of activities**, but that's for another question.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is by converting the data here, which is contact centric (meaning that each row represents a new contact, not a new company) into a company centric JSON array.

This is represented in the code below

```
var companies = {
  'names':[]
};
function organiseLeads() {
  
  const leads = leadSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    leads.splice(0,1);

  try {
    for (var i in leads) {
      var data = leads[i];
      var companyName = data[3];

      var exists = companies.names.some(function (company) {
        return company === companyName;
      });
Logger.log(exists);
      if (exists == false) {
        companies.names[companyName] = {
          'region': data[4],
          'type': data[5],
          'createDate': data[9],
          'ids': {
            'opportunityId': data[8],
            'accountId': data[7],
            'leadId': data[0]
          },
          'activities': [{
            'type': 'Lead Created',
            'date': data[9],
            'detail': data[2]
          }]
        }
      } else if (exists == true && data[9].valueOf() < companies[companyName].createDate) {
        companies.names[companyName].createDate = data[9];
        companies.names[companyName].activities.push({ 'type': 'Lead Created', 'date': data[9], 'detail': data[2] });
      } else if (exists == true && data[9].valueOf() > companies[companyName].createDate) {
        companies.names[companyName].activities.push({ 'type': 'Lead Created', 'date': data[9], 'detail': data[2] });
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
    Logger.log(exists);
     Logger.log(data);
      Logger.log(companyName);
       Logger.log(companies.names);
  }
}
```

In this context `leadSheet` refers to the dataset mentioned here. It's defined in Google Script elsewhere.

I've also tried using `companies.names.push([companyName = {}])` (with all the additional data there), but nothing happens.

What's supposed to happen is that it checks to see if the company already exists, in this array. If it doesn't, it will create it as multi-dimensional array use the company name as the primary key and then have the details as the nested key values pairs.

If the company already exists, it just makes some minor changes to that company record, and then returns the entire json array.

However, what happens is nothing. It doesn't set anything in the JSON array at all. And when i've tried to flatten the companies array, I get the error **companies.some is not a function** and the exists variable, which checks to see if company already exists, always returns false.

How do I make sure that the data gets properly pushed into the JSON array? Keep in mind that the key for the company name is dynamically generated and not a static key.

I would like to keep the JSON structure as described in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making it work with this

```
function organiseLeads() {

  const [headers, ...leads] = leadSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  try {
    for (var i in leads) {
      var [leadId, name, email, companyName, region, type, industry, accountId, oppId, createdDate] = leads[i];
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(createdDate,"GMT","dd-MM-yyyy");

      if (!companies.names.hasOwnProperty(companyName)) {
        companies.names[companyName] = {};
        companies[companyName] = {
          'region': region,
          'type': type,
          'createDate': date,
          'ids': {
            'opportunityId': oppId,
            'accountId': accountId,
            'leadId': leadId
          },
          'activities': [{
            'type': 'Lead Created',
            'date': date,
            'detail': email
          }]
        }
      } else if (companies.names.hasOwnProperty(companyName) && date.valueOf() < companies.names[companyName].createDate) {
        companies.names[companyName].createDate = date;
        companies.names[companyName].activities.push({ 'type': 'Lead Created', 'date': date, 'detail': email });
      } else if (companies.names.hasOwnProperty(companyName) && createdDate.valueOf() > companies.names[companyName].createDate) {
        companies.names[companyName].activities.push({ 'type': 'Lead Created', 'date': date, 'detail': email });
      }
    }
    Logger.log(companies)
    return companies;
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e);
    Logger.log(companies.hasOwnProperty(companyName));
    Logger.log("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s",leadId, name, email, companyName, region, type, industry, accountId, oppId, date);
    Logger.log(companyName);
    Logger.log(companies);
  }
```

I switched out the companies.some() for .hasOwnProperty(), as it is a better check and faster. I also had to declare the company before I added in the nested key value pair first. And lastly I added a nested element called 'names'. I'm not sure I need this.

I think @Cooper has a great answer that would make it easier to look at condense the code, it just didn't solve my particular use case problem. I will try to update his solution to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

#### Company Centric JSON

```
function companyCentricJson() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hA,...vs]= sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const json = vs.reduce((a,[id,name,eml,co,reg,type,indus,acct,oppo,date],i) => {
    if(!a.obj.hasOwnProperty(co)) {
      a.obj[co] = [];
      a.obj[co].push(hA)
      a.obj[co].push([id,name,eml,co,reg,type,indus,acct,oppo,date]);
      a.obj.pA.push(co);
    } else {
      a.obj[co].push([id,name,eml,co,reg,type,indus,acct,oppo,date])
    }
    return a;
  },{obj:{pA:[]},json:function(){return JSON.stringify(this.obj)}}).json();
  Logger.log(json);
  return json;
}
```

Data Sheet:

| Id | Name | Email | Company | Region | Type | Industry | Account Id | Opportunity Id | Create Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123446 | Jon L | Jon L@Company 1.com | Company 1 | None | Enterprise |  | 9078900.00% | 44567800.00% | 01-03-2020 |
| 123468 | Frank F | Frank F@Company 2.com | Company 2 | None | Mobile Operator | Telecommunications | 9076500.00% | 77654400.00% | 01-03-2020 |
| 123490 | Alex Y | Alex Y@Company 3.com | Company 3 | EMEA |  |  | 9074100.00% | 110741000.00% | 01-03-2020 |
| 123512 | Ilya A | Ilya A@Company 4.com | Company 4 | None |  |  | 9071700.00% | 143827600.00% | 01-03-2020 |
| 123534 | Mike M | Mike M@Company 5.com | Company 5 | None |  |  | 9069300.00% | 176914200.00% | 01-03-2020 |
| 123556 | Narimon O | Narimon O@Company 6.com | Company 6 | None | Service Provider |  | 9066900.00% | 210000800.00% | 01-03-2020 |
| 123578 | Sagar S | Sagar S@Company 7.com | Company 7 | None |  |  | 9064500.00% | 243087400.00% | 02-03-2020 |
| 123600 | John C | John C@Company 8.com | Company 8 | None |  |  | 9062100.00% | 276174000.00% | 02-03-2020 |
| 123622 | Pete r | Pete r@Company 9.com | Company 9 | None |  |  | 9059700.00% | 309260600.00% | 02-03-2020 |
| 123644 | Ivelin I | Ivelin I@Company 10.com | Company 10 | None |  |  | 9057300.00% | 342347200.00% | 02-03-2020 |
| 123666 | Reginald R | Reginald R@Company 11.com | Company 11 | None | Enterprise |  | 9054900.00% | 375433800.00% | 02-03-2020 |
| 123688 | Yossi R | Yossi R@Company 12.com | Company 12 | None | Enterprise |  | 9052500.00% | 408520400.00% | 02-03-2020 |
| 123710 | Joey K | Joey K@Company 13.com | Company 13 | None | Service Provider |  | 9050100.00% | 441607000.00% | 02-03-2020 |

The JSON:

```
{"pA":["Company 1","Company 2","Company 3","Company 4","Company 5","Company 6","Company 7","Company 8","Company 9","Company 10","Company 11","Company 12","Company 13"],"Company 1":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123446,"Jon L","Jon L@Company 1.com","Company 1","None","Enterprise","",90789,445678,"2020-03-01T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 2":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123468,"Frank F","Frank F@Company 2.com","Company 2","None","Mobile Operator","Telecommunications",90765,776544,"2020-03-01T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 3":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123490,"Alex Y","Alex Y@Company 3.com","Company 3","EMEA","","",90741,1107410,"2020-03-01T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 4":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123512,"Ilya A","Ilya A@Company 4.com","Company 4","None","","",90717,1438276,"2020-03-01T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 5":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123534,"Mike M","Mike M@Company 5.com","Company 5","None","","",90693,1769142,"2020-03-01T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 6":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123556,"Narimon O","Narimon O@Company 6.com","Company 6","None","Service Provider","",90669,2100008,"2020-03-01T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 7":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123578,"Sagar S","Sagar S@Company 7.com","Company 7","None","","",90645,2430874,"2020-03-02T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 8":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123600,"John C","John C@Company 8.com","Company 8","None","","",90621,2761740,"2020-03-02T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 9":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123622,"Pete r","Pete r@Company 9.com","Company 9","None","","",90597,3092606,"2020-03-02T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 10":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123644,"Ivelin I","Ivelin I@Company 10.com","Company 10","None","","",90573,3423472,"2020-03-02T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 11":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123666,"Reginald R","Reginald R@Company 11.com","Company 11","None","Enterprise","",90549,3754338,"2020-03-02T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 12":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123688,"Yossi R","Yossi R@Company 12.com","Company 12","None","Enterprise","",90525,4085204,"2020-03-02T07:00:00.000Z"]],"Company 13":[["Id","Name","Email","Company","Region","Type","Industry","Account Id","Opportunity Id","Create Date"],[123710,"Joey K","Joey K@Company 13.com","Company 13","None","Service Provider","",90501,4416070,"2020-03-02T07:00:00.000Z"]]}
```

#### A Dialog to Read your data

GS:

```
function getCompanyInfo(name="Company 1") {
  const vs = JSON.parse(companyCentricJSON())[name];
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  return vs.reduce((a,c,i) => {
    if(i == 0) {
      a.hl += '<tr>'
      c.forEach(e => a.hl += '<th>' + e + '</th>');
      a.hl += '</tr>'
    } else {
      a.hl += '<tr>'
      c.forEach(e => a.hl += '<td>' + e + '</td>');
      a.hl += '</tr>'
    }
    return a;
  },{hl:"<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>",getHtml:function(){return this.hl + '</table>'}}).getHtml();
}

function getMySelects() {
  return JSON.parse(companyCentricJSON()).pA
}

function launchCompanyCentricDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah4").setWidth(1200),"Company Centric Info Dialog")
}
```

html: ("ah4.html"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="sel1" onChange="displayData();" placeholder="Select Company"></select>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <div id="msg"></div>

    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function (obj){
          updateSelect(obj)
        })
        .getMySelects()
      }
     function updateSelect(vA,id){
      var id=id || 'sel1';
      var select = document.getElementById(id);
      select.options.length = 0; 
      vA.unshift("");
      for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
      }
    }
    function displayData() {
      let val = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function (hl) {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = hl;
      })
      .getCompanyInfo(val);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Dialog Demo:

[image]

Comment: thanks for this. Lot to unpack here. However, my end goal, as mentioned in my question is to build a timeline of events. This particular snippet is preparing the core companies and the ids of the companies. The next step is to take additional datasets that represent activities and merge them into the JSON array. That will be under the 'activities' key in the JSON structure in my code. This doesn't take into account the key value pairs and structure that I need for built my total dataset. Thanks for your patience, not sure if it was clear.